# Android billing client purchase SKU not getting

Tags: java, android, mobile, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

```
public class CreditBuyActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements PurchasesUpdatedListener {
ImageView creditArrowBack;
private BillingClient billingClient;
RelativeLayout relative1, relative2,relative3;
private Map<String, SkuDetails> skuDetailsMap = new HashMap<>();

private String[] textArray1 = {"Premium üyelik ile beğeni hakkın artsın","Premiumlulara özel, kredi ile hesap boostlama","Premium üye ol ayrıcalıklara eriş"};

private String[] textArray = {
        "Kredilerin ile sohbetin yarıda kalmasın","Premiumlulara özel, kredi ile hesap boostlama",
        "Kredi ile daha fazla kişiyi beğenebilirsin"};

TextView creditAmount;

TextView changeText,changeText1;

RelativeLayout relativePremium, relativePremium1,relativePremium2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_credit_buy);

    creditArrowBack = findViewById(R.id.imageBackArrow);

    relativePremium = findViewById(R.id.relativePremium);
    relativePremium1 = findViewById(R.id.relativePremium2);
    relativePremium2 = findViewById(R.id.relativePremium3);

    changeText = findViewById(R.id.changeText);
    changeText1 = findViewById(R.id.changeText1);



    creditArrowBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(CreditBuyActivity.this,MainScreen.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    creditAmount = findViewById(R.id.textCreditAmount);



    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    assert user != null;
    String currentId = user.getUid();

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference("profiles").child(currentId).child("credit");

    reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            Integer credit = snapshot.getValue(Integer.class);

            creditAmount.setText(String.valueOf(credit));


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });


    relative1 = findViewById(R.id.relative1);
    relative2 = findViewById(R.id.relative2);
    relative3 = findViewById(R.id.relative3);

    relative1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startPurchaseFlow("10tl");
        }
    });

    relative2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startPurchaseFlow("40tl");
        }
    });

    relative3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startPurchaseFlow("80tl");
        }
    });

    relativePremium.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startPurchaseFlow("onemonthplan");
        }
    });

    relativePremium1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startPurchaseFlow("139tl");
        }
    });

    relativePremium2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startPurchaseFlow("499tl");

        }
    });



    setupBillingClient();

    animateTextChange();
    animateTextChange1();

}

private void setupBillingClient() {
    billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this)
            .setListener(this)
            .enablePendingPurchases()
            .build();

    billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBillingSetupFinished(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult) {
            if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                querySkuDetails();
                querySkuDetailsMonth();
                querySkuDetailsYear();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
            // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
            // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
        }
    });
}

private void querySkuDetails() {
    List<String> skuList = Arrays.asList("10tl", "40tl", "80tl","499tl");
    SkuDetailsParams.Builder params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
    params.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);

    billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build(), new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSkuDetailsResponse(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult, List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
            if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && skuDetailsList != null) {
                for (SkuDetails skuDetails : skuDetailsList) {
                    skuDetailsMap.put(skuDetails.getSku(), skuDetails);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

private void querySkuDetailsYear(){
    List<String> skuList = Arrays.asList("139tl");
    SkuDetailsParams.Builder params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
    params.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);

    billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build(), new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSkuDetailsResponse(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult, List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
            if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && skuDetailsList != null) {
                for (SkuDetails skuDetails : skuDetailsList) {
                    skuDetailsMap.put(skuDetails.getSku(), skuDetails);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

private void querySkuDetailsMonth() {
    List<String> skuList = Arrays.asList("onemonthplan");
    SkuDetailsParams.Builder params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
    params.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS);

    billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build(), new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSkuDetailsResponse(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult, List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
            if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && skuDetailsList != null) {
                for (SkuDetails skuDetails : skuDetailsList) {
                    skuDetailsMap.put(skuDetails.getSku(), skuDetails);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

private void startPurchaseFlow(String skuId) {
    SkuDetails skuDetails = skuDetailsMap.get(skuId);
    if (skuDetails != null) {
        BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                .setSkuDetails(skuDetails)
                .build();
        billingClient.launchBillingFlow(this, billingFlowParams);
    }
}

@Override
public void onPurchasesUpdated(BillingResult billingResult, List<Purchase> purchases) {
    if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && purchases != null) {
        for (com.android.billingclient.api.Purchase purchase : purchases) {
            handlePurchase(purchase);
        }
    }
}

private void handlePurchase(Purchase purchase) {
    // Handle the purchase here (e.g., grant the user access to the purchased item)
    if (!purchase.isAcknowledged()) {
        // Acknowledge the purchase
        acknowledgePurchase(purchase.getPurchaseToken());

    }

    // Grant the user access to the purchased item
    ArrayList<String> sku = purchase.getSkus();
    int quantity = purchase.getQuantity();
    if ("10tl".equals(sku)) {
        // Grant access to the "diamond100" product
        grantAccessToDiamond100();
    }else if ("40tl".equals(sku)) {
        // Grant access to the "diamond300" product
        grantAccessToDiamond300();
    }else if ("80tl".equals(sku)) {
        // Grant access to the "diamond559" product
        grantAccessToDiamond559();
    }else if ("onemonthplan".equals(sku)){
        grantAccessToOneMonthPlan();
    }else if ("139tl".equals(sku)){
        grantAccessToSixMonthPlan();
    }else if ("499tl".equals(sku)){
        grantAccessToOneYearPlan();
    }


}

private void grantAccessToDiamond300(){

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    String currentUserId = user.getUid();
    DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference("profiles").child(currentUserId);



    // Retrieve the current "coins" value
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            Integer credit = snapshot.child("credit").getValue(Integer.class);

            Log.d("CreditBuyActivity", "onDataChange: " +credit);
            int newCredit = credit + 500;

            reference.child("credit").setValue(newCredit);


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

}

private void grantAccessToDiamond559() {
    DatabaseReference databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid(); // Kullanıcının UID'si

    // Retrieve the current "coins" value
    databaseRef.child("profiles").child(userId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                Integer credit = snapshot.child("credit").getValue(Integer.class);

                int newCredit = credit + 1000;

                databaseRef.child("credit").setValue(newCredit);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Failed to update coin count.", error.toException());
        }
    });
}

private void grantAccessToDiamond100() {
    // Grant the user access to the "diamond100" product
    // This could involve updating the user's subscription status in your app or on your server

    // Increase "diamond100" count in the database
    DatabaseReference databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid(); // Kullanıcının UID'si

    // Retrieve the current "coins" value
    databaseRef.child("profiles").child(userId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                Integer credit = snapshot.child("credit").getValue(Integer.class);

                int newCredit = credit + 100;

                databaseRef.child("credit").setValue(newCredit);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Failed to update coin count.", error.toException());
        }
    });
}

private void acknowledgePurchase(String purchaseToken) {
    AcknowledgePurchaseParams acknowledgePurchaseParams =
            AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder()
                    .setPurchaseToken(purchaseToken)
                    .build();
    billingClient.acknowledgePurchase(acknowledgePurchaseParams, new AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAcknowledgePurchaseResponse(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult) {
            if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                // Purchase acknowledged successfully

                
                Toast.makeText(CreditBuyActivity.this, "Satın alım başarılı", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

}

private void grantAccessToOneMonthPlan() {

    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    String currentUserId = user.getUid();

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference("profiles").child(currentUserId);

    reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()){
                    boolean isPremium = snapshot.child("premium").getValue(Boolean.class);
                    Log.d("CreditBuyActivity", "onDataChange: "+ isPremium);

                    reference.child("premium").setValue(true);

                }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

}

private void grantAccessToSixMonthPlan() {
    // Grant the user access to the six-month plan
    // This could involve updating the user's subscription status in your app or on your server
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    String currentUserId = user.getUid();

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference("profiles").child(currentUserId);

    reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()){
                boolean isPremium = snapshot.child("premium").getValue(Boolean.class);
                Log.d("CreditBuyActivity", "onDataChange: "+ isPremium);

                reference.child("premium").setValue(true);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}

private void grantAccessToOneYearPlan() {
    // Grant the user access to the one-year plan
    // This could involve updating the user's subscription status in your app or on your server
    DatabaseReference databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid(); // Kullanıcının UID'si

    // Retrieve the current "coins" value
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    String currentUserId = user.getUid();

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference("profiles").child(currentUserId);

    reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()){
                boolean isPremium = snapshot.child("premium").getValue(Boolean.class);
                Log.d("CreditBuyActivity", "onDataChange: "+ isPremium);

                reference.child("premium").setValue(true);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

I'm reaching out regarding an issue you might be able to help me with. I've recently encountered a situation related to in-app purchases and access to purchased content.

The scenario is as follows: After successfully completing a purchase, I'm facing difficulties in granting users access to the purchased content. I've verified that the SKUs (Stock Keeping Units) are correctly set up, and the Firebase connections seem to be in order as well.

Given that the purchase process is successfully concluding, the challenge seems to lie in delivering the appropriate content associated with the purchased SKU. I've ensured that the SKU values match both in the code and on the Google Play Developer Console. Additionally, I've double-checked the configuration of Firebase connections to ensure accuracy.

If you have any insights or suggestions on how to address this issue, I would greatly appreciate your assistance. I'm open to any recommendations or potential solutions that could help me grant users access to the content they've purchased.

Thank you in advance for your time and expertise. Your input could be immensely valuable in resolving this issue and ensuring a smooth user experience.

Comment: exactly what problem you are facing? are able to purchase SKU successfully or getting the issue in that flow?

Comment: When the user makes a successful purchase, the user's credit amount does not increase.